# Unable to copy image from URL in PHP with upload class

Tags: php, class, oop, upload

I'm trying to make a upload class with PHP. so this is my first PHP class:

```
//Create Class
class Upload{
  //Remote Image Upload
  function Remote($Image){
    $Content = file_get_contents($Image);
    if(copy($Content, '/test/sdfsdfd.jpg')){
      return "UPLOADED";
    }else{
      return "ERROR";
    }
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
$Upload = new Upload();
echo $Upload->Remote('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg');
```

problem is, this class is not working. where is the problem? I'm new with PHP classes and trying to learn it.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` expects filesystem paths, e.g.

```
copy('/path/to/source', '/path/to/destination');
```

You're passing in the literal image you fetched, so it's going to be

```
copy('massive pile of binary garbage that will be treated as a filename', '/path/to/destination');
```

You want

```
file_put_contents('/test/sdfsdfg.jpg', $Content);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function is used for copying files that you have permission to copy.

Since you're getting the contents of the file first, you could use [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

```php
<?php

//Remote Image Upload
function Remote($Image){
    $Content = file_get_contents($Image);
    // Create the file
    if (!$fp = fopen('img.png', 'w')) {
        echo "Failed to create image file.";
    }

    // Add the contents
    if (fwrite($fp, $Content) === false) {
        echo "Failed to write image file contents.";
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: i need to fix the class my friend!

Comment: @Alireza I edited it so you can see what the function would look like.

Comment: @Alireza which part isn't working?  Testing this on my machine works well.  Are you getting any sort of message?

Comment: thank you for your answers, but after using the file_put_contents function, everything is ok now

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to download a image, you could also use the `imagejpeg`-method of php to ensure you do not end up with any corrupted file format afterwards (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

- download the target as "String"
- create a image resource out of it.
- save it as jpeg, using the proper method:

inside your method:

```
$content = file_get_contents($Image);
$img = imagecreatefromstring($content);
return imagejpeg($img, "Path/to/targetFile");
```

In order to have `file_get_contents` working correctly you need to ensure that `allow_url_fopen` is set to `1` in your php ini: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Most managed hosters disable this by default. Either contact the support therefore or if they will not enable `allow_url_fopen`, you need to use another attempt, for example using cURL for file download. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

U can use the following snippet to check whether its enabled or not:

```
if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
   echo "Enabled";
} else{
   echo "Disabled";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is more download (to the server) then upload. [stream_copy_to_stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php).

```
class Remote
{
    public static function download($in, $out)
    {
        $src = fopen($in, "r");
        if (!$src) {
            return 0;
        }
        $dest = fopen($out, "w");
        if (!$dest) {
            return 0;
        }

        $bytes = stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest);

        fclose($src); fclose($dest);

        return $bytes;
    }
}

$remote = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg';
$local = __DIR__ . '/test/sdfsdfd.jpg';

echo (Remote::download($remote, $local) > 0 ? "OK" : "ERROR");
```